# Lambda Alex Skill session attribute is undefined

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am getting this error in Lambda while trying to upload my files,

```
{
 "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'application' of undefined",
"errorType": "TypeError",
"stackTrace": [
"AlexaSkill.execute (/var/task/AlexaSkill.js:83:62)",
"exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:170:10)"
]
}
```

Looks like from line 83 of AlexaSkill.js:

```
console.log("session applicationId: " + event.session.application.applicationId);
```

the session attribute is undefined. Not really sure what's causing

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Is your lamda skill processing a request from Alexa?

Comment: We have put together a few tools to help.lambda skill developement. Check it out: https://bespoken.tools

Comment: I am making a skill, asking alexa "Who is at the door", the files are uploaded in Amazon S3, you can see the project here https://github.com/G-mel/Who-Is-At-The-Door

Comment: The first call to this is in the index.js file in the last few lines "exports.handler= function(event,context) I'm having the same problem but i've found out the root cause,but not the solution, so i've commented here to get notifications.It's been long since you've posted this question, have you figured out the solution?

Comment: I have not figure it out yet, I'm waiting to see if amazon can help me figure this out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out using my sherlock holmes-like skills obtained from excessive mistakes made, Go into your aws lambda account, go to your function, Since you've uploaded the code, click the actions->configure test event->select "Alexa start session" from sample event template, and in the bottom, click save and test button, there, it works :)

If you found this answer to solve your question, please give a tick for my answer